# the_content() without <p> before - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm running 'the loop' on my index page, and when I put the_content() on the loop its automatically adding `'<p>..</p>'` between the content and I want to cancel it.

any ways? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add in your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: How do you mean return it? How can you break between paragraphs? Wrap all your paragraphs in `<p>` tags manually.

Comment: I didn't accept because I can accept an answer about 7 min after the answer was written :) by thw way, I mean return it because when I add this filter it cancels the <p> in all of the_content() on the website. I want to cancel it on specific area. maybe can I do something like: add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?

Comment: Yes `add_filter ('the_content','wpautop');`works. Disable wpautop conditionally within your loop where you're displaying the content rather than in the functions.php if you only want disabled it in certain cases.